# CSS: div padding not starting from top of parent container

Tags: css

At [this page](http://vmpersonal.com/home%20page%20column%20snippets.html), the padding of `.snippet-action a` is starting beyond the top of `.snippet-action`.

[image]

What changes do I need to make `.snippet-action a`'s padding-top start at the top of `.snippet-action`?

Help appreciated.

```
<style>
.snippet {
    background-color: #FFD000;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius: 9px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
    width: 48%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    float: left;
}
.snippet-image {z-index: 998;}
.snippet-image img {width: 100%; height: auto; z-index: 998;}
.snippet-text {
    width: 94%;
    margin: -42px 3% 0 3%;
    padding: 3%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
}
.snippet-action {
    background-color: #FFD000;
    padding-left: 3%; margin-top: -38px; 
    height: 38px;
    max-width: 168px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
}
.snippet-action a {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #291B65;
    padding: 18px 0 8px 3%; 
}
</style>

<div class="one-third">
    <div class="snippet">
        <div class="snippet-image">
            <img src="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/product-personalized-consultation.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="snippet-text">
            <h3>Personalized Consultation</h3>
            <p>The Personalised Fitness Consultation is a premium service. The client has the opportunity to have a face-to-face conversation with Victor (VM Personal CEO), in order to develop the best... strategy towards taking your fitness to the next level.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="snippet-action">
            <a href="#">Learn More</a>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to `.snippet-action a`. By default an `a` element is an `inline` element, and `inline` elements do not have vertical layout on the page. To make the element have vertical layout, use `inline-block` or change it to a block level element.

```css
.snippet {
    background-color: #FFD000;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius: 9px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
    width: 48%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    float: left;
}
.snippet-image {z-index: 998;}
.snippet-image img {width: 100%; height: auto; z-index: 998;}
.snippet-text {
    width: 94%;
    margin: -42px 3% 0 3%;
    padding: 3%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
}
.snippet-action {
    background-color: #FFD000;
    padding-left: 3%; margin-top: -38px; 
    height: 38px;
    max-width: 168px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
}
.snippet-action a {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #291B65;
    padding: 18px 0 8px 3%; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="one-third">
    <div class="snippet">
        <div class="snippet-image">
            <img src="http://vmpersonal.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/product-personalized-consultation.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="snippet-text">
            <h3>Personalized Consultation</h3>
            <p>The Personalised Fitness Consultation is a premium service. The client has the opportunity to have a face-to-face conversation with Victor (VM Personal CEO), in order to develop the best... strategy towards taking your fitness to the next level.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="snippet-action">
            <a href="#">Learn More</a>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 0):

add `display:inline-block` and `padding-left` and `padding-right`

```
 .snippet-action {
        background-color: #FFD000;
        margin-top: -38px;
        height: 38px;
        padding-left: 8px;
        padding-right: 8px;
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 45px;
        max-width: 168px;
        border-top-right-radius: 8px;
        -moz-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
        z-index: 1000;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```